# List.Select() method does not execute method inside the Func<>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Why are the names NOT being printed in this given example?

`customer.Select()` method really NOT printing the data. Is it really NOT executing the `Func<>` inside the `Select()` method OR something different is happening here??

**Code:**

```
public static void Main()
{
     var customers = new List<Customer>()
     {
         new Customer() { Name = "Bill" }, 
         new Customer() { Name = "Steve" }
    };

    customers.Select(
    c =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
        return 0;
    });

    Console.Read();
}
```

Would anybody please do let me know why it is NOT executing OR printing?

Comment: See also [Something better than `.ToArray()` to force enumeration of LINQ output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314100/) which has an answer by Jon Skeet which suggests a `foreach` loop with empty loop body, or alternatively **`.LastOrDefault()`**.

Comment: `WriteLine` has `String.Format` "built-in", just replace the `+` with a `,`, but he doesn't need it just for this simple expression, `"Name is " + c.Name` is simpler.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know that. I always thought the opposite :)

Comment: And by "simpler" here, I'm probably prematurely optimizing. If he wants to use string.Format syntax, he should just do what I just said, replace the `+` with a `,` and all is good, but just using the `+` is slightly cheaper when dealing with such simple expressions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Select` does not do anything *unless you enumerate over the results*.

As mentioned in the comment below, this is called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) (thanks [@BCdotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648075/bcdotnet))

You are probably looking for `ForEach` instead of `Select`:

```
customers.ForEach(
    c =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
    });
```

Select is a "projection", it takes a collection as input, and produces a new collection that when enumerated over will call the specified delegate on each element of the input collection, and the result from each such delegate call is the elements of the output collection.

Since you only said "When you later enumerate over this, this is what you should do", and then never enumerated over it, nothing happened.

`Select` is thus more a "recipe" of how to take one collection and create another. Until you execute the recipe (enumerating over it), the recipe is just that, a recipe.

Having said all that, unless you actually *need* it to use Select, this is what you should do:

```
foreach (var c in customers)
    Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
```

On the other hand, if you *really need it to use Select*, you can use the following ways to enumerate over it:

1. Call one of the many methods that will "force enumeration to do its job", in order of (my opinionated) applicability:

   - LastOrDefault
   - ToList
   - ToArray

   Example:

   ```
   customers.Select(
       c =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
           return 0;
       }).LastOrDefault();
   ```
2. Just plain enumerate over it:

   ```
   foreach (var dummy in customers.Select(
       c =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
           return 0;
       }))
   { } // do nothing here, empty loop body
   ```

---

Lastly, you're using `Console.WriteLine` incorrectly, you've added a parameter, but then use string concatenation to build the resulting string, meaning you will see this:

```
Name is {0}Bill
Name is {0}Steve
```

Instead, here's my final advice:

```
foreach (var c in customers)
    Console.WriteLine("Name is " + c.Name);
```

Comment: See also: [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: If you have a lazy source like `x.Select(c => { ... })`, surely you can force enumeration of it by saying `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`. However that will create an array that will need to be re-sized (allocate new larger array, and copy over from the old one) once in a while during the iteration. If you don't want the resulting collection, but only the side-effects, you can append `.LastOrDefault()` instead. So go from `x.Select(c => { ... })` to `x.Select(c => { ... }).LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: Why not use `{ }` instead of `;` for an empty loop body? It is easier to read and understand correctly. The C# compiler should know that they are equivalent.

Comment: While I agree with everything you said @JeppeStigNielsen (and probably more so if you write more comments here :)), *my* main problem here is that most of it is nonsensical ("it" meaning the problem in the question, *not what you wrote!*), the OP should not create a collection if he doesn't need one. He just needs the `foreach` loop and he's done, the rest is just a "bonus".

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute it :) - add ToList()

```
customers.Select(
                c =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}" + c.Name);
                    return 0;
                }).ToList();
```