# What is the better empty foreach: Empty control statement or empty block?

Tags: c#, foreach, resharper

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314130/1051244) I wrote this empty foreach loop:

```
foreach (var result in aggregationResult) ;
```

Now ReSharper complains about "Empty control statement body" and wants to change this loop to use an empty block:

```
foreach (var result in aggregationResult)
{
}
```

Q: Do both loops force to enumerate the IEnumerable? Because this was the intention of this code.

Comment: Yes, both will force the sequence to be enumerated - but I'd argue that the latter is clearer, especially when you add a comment in the braces of "Deliberately empty - just trying to force the sequence to be fully enumerated".

Comment: (I've edited my answer to do that too :)

Comment: Why don't you just convert to list to enumerate the IEnumerable? Why do you use an IEnumerable at all? If R# complains both way, there is certainly Something that can be change ;)

Comment: @Oarzy: You are right. I could use aggregationResult.ToList() to force enumeration. But that was not the question.